# Java Deduction gives wrong result

Tags: java

In My Java code I'm trying to do following

```
    double a=1769.58;
    double b=986.58;
    double c=a-b;
    System.out.println("Result "+c);
```

This is retuning the result as  782.9999999999999. but it should be 783.00 what is wrong with this.how can I get correct value and what is the reason for this?

Comment: http://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: check out 2.00-1.10 ;)

Comment: Side note that you should denote `double`s as `1769.58D` and `986.58D`.

Answer (score 0):

It's because computer can't stored exactly the good value of floating point.
See [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16082201/3587992) to learn more about this problem.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
double a=1769.58;
double b=986.58;
int c=(int)a-(int)b;
```

Comment: This is identical to `Double.compare(a, b)`